# Integral function that works as an upper bound

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $\displaystyle f(x,t)=\left|\frac{e^{-t \sqrt{x}}}{\sqrt{x}}\right|$ where $t>0$

I need to find a function $g(x)$ such that $f(x,t) \leq g(x)$ and $\displaystyle \int_1^{\infty} g(x) \ dx$ is finite, which means that $g(x)$ is integrable over  $[1,\infty)$.

Comment: For what values of $t$ should the inequality $f(x,t) \leq g(x)$ be true?

Comment: @sudeep5221 t is strictly greater than 0

Comment: There's no need for absolute values, as the argument is always positive. Have you tried integrating $f(x,t)$ with respect to $x$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such function. If $f(x,t) \leq g(x)$ for all $x$ and all $t >0$ we can let $t\to 0$ to see that $g(x) \geq \frac 1 {\sqrt x}$. But then $g$ is not integrable on $[1,\infty)$.